# Menu item not visible in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu, androidx

I would like to show a menu in my fragment. I've done this a million times, yet it is not working now for some reason. This is the first time I experiment with the new **androidx library, maybe bug?**

**Fragment:**

```
public class FragmentDogs extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dogs, container, false);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_dogs, menu);

    }
}
```

**Activity:**

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentDogs()).commit();
    }
}
```

**Menu:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/dogs_add_menu_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_plus"

        android:title="@string/dogs"  />
```

**Gradle:**

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.platinum"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Need to add `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

Comment: Try removing **super** call.

Comment: Try adding `menu.clear();` before inflating the menu.

Comment: Is the menu item there at all? I mean, is it possibly just an issue with the icon not showing? Can you click where the item should be?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the custom `toolbar` to the Fragment Layout and as `SupportActionBar`.

**Your Fragment Layout**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetEnd="50dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="50dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:title="testtext"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Your Fragment class**

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourfragmentlayout, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("YourFragment");

    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_dogs, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
}
```

If *YourFragment()* is red underlined

[image]

Make sure that you are using

> `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

instead of

> `import android.app.Fragment;`

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the closing tag on `menu.xml`, which possibly should end with `</menu>`.

the `testInstrumentationRunner` is not the correct test-runner for `androidx`, along with the other test dependencies. `androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0` would be the proper dependency for the `Fragment` class. see the [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) for further `androidx` dependencies, which you might be lacking; alike `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2` for the `AppCompatActivity`.

it might be a [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... first fix the dependencies - and then the menu.